# Inheritance behaviour in java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Can anyone explain , why this shows error in eclipse , but run successfully without any error.I have paste the code below.

Parent class:

```
public class Parent {
    /*Parent class method*/
    public void show() { 
        System.out.println("Parent class show called");
    }
}
```

Child Class:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    /* Child class overridden method*/  
    private void show() { 
        // this line show error in eclipse
        System.out.println("Child class show called ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Child();
        p.show();
    }
}
```

OutPut is: Parent class show called

Comment: You have to mentioned what error you are getting ? How someone from out of the your development environment know?

Comment: You can´t change the visibility of a overriden method

Comment: How can it run if eclipse shows an error? Btw you can't reduce the visibility of inherited methods.

Comment: Tom, you are right , it shows error but runs successfully.

Comment: And how do you know that you're running this version and not an old one which was build without any problem?

Comment: You can try this.I am not using old compiled code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because eclipse compiler can create class files even in presence of compilation errors. Please follow below link for this .

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-java-builder.htm

But if you will open child class created by this in java decompiler then you will see below code.

```
    public class Child extends Parent
    {
          private void show()
          {
              throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problem: Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from Parent");
          }

          public static void main(String[] args)
          {
                Parent p = new Child();
                p.show();
          }
    }
```

So basically what eclipse is doing that it is ignoring that error and creating a class file with that error and when class file is present then you can run your code and because at compile time it is able to find out that parent has method show so it is calling that method.
But if you change reference from Parent to Child class then it will give you exception at runtime.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from Parent
    at com.nucleus.finnone.tbs.Child.show(Child.java:5)
    at com.nucleus.finnone.tbs.Child.main(Child.java:12)

Answer (score 5):

You can not reduce the visibilty of a method by inheritance.

So the visibility in your child class must be `public` not `private`.

```
public class Child extends Parent{
/* Child class overridden method*/  
 public void show(){ // this line show error in eclipse
     System.out.println("Child class show called ");

 }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Parent p = new Child();
        p.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: I know this , but why it runs successfully.

Comment: @SantoshSingh you are maybe running an old compiled code from before the error was added

Comment: Clean the project in eclipse. Project-->clean. Try to run it again, it will not run.

Comment: Please you can also try in your eclipse!

Comment: @SantoshSingh You are right. The code is working. Looks like the java compiler ignore th method `show` in the child class. Really strange.

Comment: Now you get it!! Can anyone Explain its reason.

Comment: @neomega I have tried it by creating the classes in my eclipse. It runs.

Comment: Well then the eclipse compiler seems to be broken. Try it with 'javac' instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reduce the visibility of a method in java.
The `show()` method in the Child class must be `public`.
The error will go away then and you should have your output `Child class show called`.

Comment: Yes i know that according to java standard , i can not reduce the visibility.
But I reduce still the code runs successfully.